# Updating MiKTeX: again errors

Tags: xetex, errors, miktex

After today's update of MiKTeX I got lot of errors like this:

```
! \textfont 192 is undefined (character ???).
\beamer@doifinframe ...v 10^{13}\;\text {cm}^{-3}$
                                                   is rated as high for heli...
l.345 \end{frame}

? h
Somewhere in the math formula just ended, you used the
stated character from an undefined font family. For example,
plain TeX doesn't allow \it or \sl in subscripts. Proceed,
and I'll try to forget that I needed that character.
```

Such errors occur when I use xelatex to compile my documents. Initially I've got such errors for beamer class but latter I found similar errors for revtex class. Here is typical font settings for my docs:

```
\usepackage[math-style=ISO,bold-style=ISO]{unicode-math}
%\setmathfont[version=lm,Color=660000]{Latin Modern Math}
%\setmathfont[version=asana,Color=000000]{Asana Math}% <== мой выбор
%\setmathfont[version=xits,Color=000000]{XITS Math}
\setmathfont[version=cambria,Color=000066]{Cambria Math}
%\setmathfont[version=cambria]{Cambria Math}

%\mathversion{lm} % не показывает \vec{\bm\varkappa}
%\mathversion{xits}
%\mathversion{asana}
\mathversion{cambria}
```

I tried various fonts with the same result. The errors occur in math formulas but a compiled document looks fine. None errors occur if I use pdflatex instead of xelatex. Fortunately, I have TeX Live 2013 (which I have not updated) and it works fine.

**Can someone tell me what to do with these errors?**

**UPDATE:** MWE:

```
% !Mode:: TeX:UTF-8
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifxetex}
\ifxetex
    \usepackage{unicode-math}
    \setmathfont{Cambria Math}
\fi
\begin{document}
    $$
      \varepsilon_{-}
    $$

    $$
      =\varepsilon_{l}
    $$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Refresh FNDB and Update Formats from the MiKTeX Settings interface.

Comment: @karlkoeller: unfortunately this did not help. I tried several times.

Comment: In the last 3-4 days all MiKTeX executables have been updated. I've found already found a bug in `mpost.exe` and opened a bug ticket at http://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/bugs/. Do you have a MNWE to check? Probably there is a bug in `xelatex.exe` as well.

Comment: @karlkoeller: I've just added MWE.

Comment: It works for me. Try updating again, I think the executables have been further modified.

Comment: I get the errors too and have no idea why you don't, @karlkoeller. There are no more updates available, and I refreshed FNDB and updated formats both as admin and as user. In the MWE the problem seems to be caused by 'unicode-math' (for both xelatex and lualatex) and the minus sign in the subscript (or superscript for that matter). But other characters in subscript or superscript cause it too. The error message always seems to refer to `MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\tipa\t3cmr.fd`.

Comment: @dapperdan I don't know... Try this: in MiKTeX Settings -> Format, manually build formats for xetex and xelatex.

Comment: @karlkoeller: No that does not help. They are both updated "automatically" as well. Also tried CLI (initexmf), but no success. LuaTeX indeed gives a "can't find format file `miktex-luatex.fmt'!" error, but manually building formats does not change this either. Is there a way to completely clear the FNDB and formats or anything else I could try?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer [pointed out](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/message.php?msg_id=31116033) that the problem with lualatex is caused by `Umathcode` and an outdated `lualatexiniconfig.tex`. See [her post](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/message.php?msg_id=31116033) on the MiKTeX mailing list for a workaround. So this seems to rather be a xelatex bug.

Comment: @karlkoeller: Do you really don't get an error? If yes could you compile a small document with xelatex: only article + unicode-math in the preamble and this content `\tracingall $a_{b1}$` and send me the log file?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I have tried to compile again Igor's MWE and now I get the same type of error... Note that after my comment here I've updated MiKTeX again probably twice.

Comment: Has someone issued a bug report on this?

Comment: @marczellm: [I have now](https://sourceforge.net/p/xetex/bugs/81/). See also [this post](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/122923/19662) here on tex.sx.

Comment: Ulrike has asked a very good general question on this, so I'm duping (as an answer there will sort things generally).