# Miktex amsfont problem: \scriptfont is undefined

Tags: errors, amsmath, miktex, fontspec

Today, After updating Miktex system, I have trouble with error `\scriptfont is undefined`. So I tried to reinstall Miktex 2.9.4813 (32 bit version). Everything OK, but again after updating, problem is back. I see, that this update related for example file fontspec, amsmath and so on. Does anyone have a similar problem as me?

Texlipse Console:

```
running: C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\xelatex.exe -synctex=1 -     interaction=nonstopmode --src-specials main.tex --enable-write18 
xelatex.exe> This is XeTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-0.9999.3 (MiKTeX 2.9)
...
xelatex.exe> ! \textfont 173 is undefined (character ???).
xelatex.exe> l.126           \item $V_{OH}(3.3V)>V_{IH}(5V)$
xelatex.exe>                                                ,
xelatex.exe> ! \textfont 53 is undefined (character ???).
xelatex.exe> l.126           \item $V_{OH}(3.3V)>V_{IH}(5V)$
xelatex.exe>                                                ,
xelatex.exe> [395]
xelatex.exe> ! \textfont 117 is undefined (character ???).
xelatex.exe> l.127           \item $V_{OL}(3.3V)<V_{IL}(5V)$
xelatex.exe>                                                .
xelatex.exe> ! \textfont 176 is undefined (character ???).
xelatex.exe> l.127           \item $V_{OL}(3.3V)<V_{IL}(5V)$
xelatex.exe>                                                .
xelatex.exe> <use  "../src/CES/img/level_shifting_MOSFET.pdf" >
xelatex.exe> ! \textfont 100 is undefined (character ???).
xelatex.exe> l.153         $V_{OH}(3.3V)<V_{IH}(5V)$
...
xelatex.exe> 
xelatex.exe> ! \textfont 52 is undefined (character ???).
xelatex.exe> l.153         $V_{OH}(3.3V)<V_{IH}(5V)$
...
xelatex.exe> 
xelatex.exe> ! \scriptscriptfont 108 is undefined (character ???).
xelatex.exe> l.153 ...tÃ­m $$V_{GS_{th_{max}}}<V_{OH_{min}}.$$
```

MWE:
   I came to the conclusion that the problem is with the font in mathematical environment.

```
\documentclass{book}                               
 \usepackage[log-declarations=false]{xparse} 
 \usepackage{xltxtra} 
 \usepackage{fontspec} 
    \setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text,Numbers={OldStyle,Proportional}]{Calibri} 
    \setsansfont[Mapping=tex-text,Numbers={OldStyle,Proportional}]{Candara}
    \setmonofont[Numbers=OldStyle]{Consolas}

 \usepackage{ifthen}                     
 \usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb, amsfonts, amsbsy} 
 \usepackage{accents}                    
 \usepackage{unicode-math}   
    \setmathfont{Cambria Math}  

\begin{document}   
\chapter{Chapter 1}
  \section{Section 1}
     $b_{i,j}$
\end{document}
```

I see another suspicious warning:

- Couldn't open font map file "kanjix.map"

This warning came after the update.

Same difficulties are discussed in this [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121276/updating-miktex-again-errors)

Comment: Can you provide a small example file?

Comment: That is not an example; but `\textfont 173` looks particularly suspicious; there's something wrong in your code.

Comment: But I don't understand, why this problem occured after Miktex update.

Comment: The example produces some errors, due to incompatibility of `accents` with `unicode-math`, but not the ones you get (TeX Live 2013).

Comment: MWE was updated. Please try again.

Comment: No error; I only changed the fonts, because I don't have the ones you're using. But it shouldn't make any difference.

Comment: Probably, this problem is related to Miktex system and their update to newest version.

Comment: I think you are not the only one having this problem... See [Updating MiKTeX: again errors](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/121276/27635).

Comment: I can reproduce the problem. TL13 doesn't give an error but a suspicious missing character message. It looks like an engine bug. @KhaledHosny could probably say more. I have sent a message to the xetex mailing list.

Comment: It indeed seems to be the same problem as discussed in [Updating MiKTeX: again errors](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/121276/27635). In the preamble of the MWE you just need the `\usepackage{unicode-math}` and `\setmathfont{Cambria Math}` to reproduce the problem. It also does not work with lualatex, so I'd rather suspect it to be a problem with `unicode-math`!?

Comment: FWIW: I can also reproduce the problem with XITS Math.

Comment: @dapperdan: Are you sure that you get the *same* error with lualatex? Or only an error about `Umathcode`? In the second case:  check the archive of the miktex mailing. I have described there what to do to get around this problem.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Yes, I am sorry, it is not the same error but the `Umathcode` error. Thanks for pointing that out. With your workaround (I guess you are referring to [this post](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/message.php?msg_id=31116033)), lualatex works for me again.

Comment: Has someone issued a MiKTeX bug report?

Comment: @marczellm I filed a [bug report in the MiKTeX bug tracker](https://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/bugs/2283/), allthough I am not sure whether it is a MiKTeX bug or a XeLaTeX bug

Comment: @matth: It is quite likely a XeTeX bug, so I [filed it there](https://sourceforge.net/p/xetex/bugs/81/). Christian also closed the MiKTeX bug already. See also [this post](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/122923/19662) here on tex.sx.

Comment: Ulrike has asked a very good general question on this, so I'm duping (as an answer there will sort things generally).