# Combining unicode-math fonts: Problems with \underbrace

Tags: fonts, xetex, braces, unicode-math

I switched to XeLaTeX and unicode-math a while ago. I really like the possibility to combine different fonts for mathematical symbols. But now I run into trouble by combining the `\underbrace` command with content from different fonts. I actually use Asana as my main math font, but don't like its `\underbrace`, as these are too wide and with too much space between itself and the content. Therfore I wanted to use some from another font, which gave some grapy output:

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[]{english}
\setotherlanguage[spelling=new,babelshorthands=true]{german}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
  \setmathfont{Asana-Math.otf}

\begin{document}
  Asana math Blubb
  \[
    \underbrace{1} \quad \underbrace{1+1} \quad \underbrace{1+1+1} \quad \underbrace{1+1+1+1} \quad \underbrace{1+1+1+1+1}
  \]
  \setmathfont[]{xits-math.otf}
  XITS math
  \[
    \underbrace{1} \quad \underbrace{1+1} \quad \underbrace{1+1+1} \quad \underbrace{1+1+1+1} \quad \underbrace{1+1+1+1+1}
  \]
  \setmathfont[]{Cambria Math}
  Cambria Math
  \[
    \underbrace{1} \quad \underbrace{1+1} \quad \underbrace{1+1+1} \quad \underbrace{1+1+1+1} \quad \underbrace{1+1+1+1+1}
  \]
  \setmathfont[]{latinmodern-math.otf}
  Latin modern
  \[
    \underbrace{1} \quad \underbrace{1+1} \quad \underbrace{1+1+1} \quad \underbrace{1+1+1+1} \quad \underbrace{1+1+1+1+1}
  \]
  \setmathfont[]{texgyrepagella-math.otf}
  Neo Euler
  \[
    \underbrace{1} \quad \underbrace{1+1} \quad \underbrace{1+1+1} \quad \underbrace{1+1+1+1} \quad \underbrace{1+1+1+1+1}
  \]
  Asana as math font, change font for underbrace only:
  \setmathfont[]{Asana-Math.otf}
  \[
    \underbrace{1} \quad \underbrace{1+1} \quad \underbrace{1+1+1} \quad \underbrace{1+1+1+1} \quad \underbrace{1+1+1+1+1}
  \]
  \setmathfont[range=\mathunder]{xits-math.otf}
  XITS math
  \[
    \underbrace{1} \quad \underbrace{1+1} \quad \underbrace{1+1+1} \quad \underbrace{1+1+1+1} \quad \underbrace{1+1+1+1+1}
  \]
  \setmathfont[range=\mathunder]{Cambria Math}
  Cambria Math
  \[
    \underbrace{1} \quad \underbrace{1+1} \quad \underbrace{1+1+1} \quad \underbrace{1+1+1+1} \quad \underbrace{1+1+1+1+1}
  \]
  \setmathfont[range=\mathunder]{latinmodern-math.otf}
  Latin modern
  \[
    \underbrace{1} \quad \underbrace{1+1} \quad \underbrace{1+1+1} \quad \underbrace{1+1+1+1} \quad \underbrace{1+1+1+1+1}
  \]
  \setmathfont[range=\mathunder]{texgyrepagella-math.otf}
  Neo Euler
  \[
    \underbrace{1} \quad \underbrace{1+1} \quad \underbrace{1+1+1} \quad \underbrace{1+1+1+1} \quad \underbrace{1+1+1+1+1}
  \]
\end{document}
```

Is there any workaround for this? Or is it in general no good idea to combine different math fonts?

I'm in general not so sure if to stay with unicode-math, as the compilation speed slows down, and for example the XITS font has much too narrow spacing sometimes (using XeTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-0.9998, MiKTeX 2.9)

**Annotation**

According to the first comment I just tried the `TeX Gyre Pagella Math` which also seems to be a nice font with better
underbraces than Asana-math. But this brought me just to another behavior of unicode-math with XeLaTeX I have noticed
before already but forgotten about. If I run the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{texgyrepagella-math.otf}


\begin{document}
Test.
\begin{align*}
  \frac{1}{x^2} \quad \underbrace{1+1+1+1+1}_F \underbrace{1+1}_F \underbrace{i}_F
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Some minor changes that do not directly affect the math environment can change this behavior:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{texgyrepagella-math.otf}


\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  \frac{1}{x^2} \quad \underbrace{1+1+1+1+1}_F \underbrace{1+1}_F \underbrace{i}_F
\end{align*}
Some text.
\end{document}
```

[image]

I once got a similar behavior when I did a beamer presentation (using Asana-math, if I remember correctly) where changes anywhere
in the TeX code could affect the braces in the shown way. I thought that this would maybe depend on the special circumstances of
using beamer, but apparently hopping underbraces can appear anytime. Did anybody else see such a behavior of the `\underbrace` command
before?

Comment: You should try `TeX Gyre Pagella Math` instead of `Asana Math`

Comment: The shifting braces is a big that was fixed in XeTeX 0.9999.

Comment: This is good new, but until now I avoided updating due to [link](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121769/miktex-amsfont-problem-scriptfont-is-undefined)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a bug which is now fixed.

Comment: I got the same problem with an up to date lualatex