# MiKTeX Update: Error `\textfont is undefined` with Package `url`

Tags: fonts, xetex, errors, miktex, urls

The following MWE does not compile with XeLaTeX anymore after a MiKTeX update today:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setromanfont[Path=./]{LinLibertine_R.otf}
\usepackage{url}
\urlstyle{rm}

\begin{document}
    Test: \url{http://test-website.com}
\end{document}
```

You will need the [Linux Libertine OTF fonts](http://sourceforge.net/projects/linuxlibertine/files/linuxlibertine/5.3.0/LinLibertineOTF_5.3.0_2012_07_02.tgz/download) in order to reproduce the error, but they don't need to be installed. Just place `LinLibertine_R.otf` in the same folder as your MWE TeX file.

The problem seems to be the hyphen (`-`) into the URL. The same MWE compiled without problems before the update. So far I could reproduce this issue only with this font.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Imho this is the same bug I'm try to track down for weeks (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122923/missing-chars-with-unicode-math-xelatex-texlive-2013). Your example is very valuable as it shows the problem without unicode math, I will add a link to your example in my question.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks for the notification and the pointer to your StackExchange thread; I will follow it. Hope that there is a solution soon, since this issue breaks nearly all my documents. So thanks again for your efforts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The described behavior was caused by a [bug in XeTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/131228/8305), which has been resolved now. After updating MiKTeX, the issue has been gone.