# XeTeX error with Cambria Math, very simple formula

Tags: xetex, unicode-math

This MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Cambria}
\setmathfont{Cambria Math}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}

\begin{document}
$\R^{m\times n}$
\end{document}
```

gives this error:

```
! \textfont 197 is undefined (character .5).
l.9 $\R^{m\times n}$
Somewhere in the math formula just ended, you used the
stated character from an undefined font family.
```

Why?

(Using MiKTeX 2.9, XeTeX Version 3.1415926-2.5-0.9999.3)

Comment: It seems the same problem as in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121769/miktex-amsfont-problem-scriptfont-is-undefined

Comment: @egreg You're right and also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121276/updating-miktex-again-errors So this is a MiKTeX problem.